Scheduling optimization of workers and tasks based on a skills matrix over a fixed period
I'm seeking guidance on formulating a complex scheduling optimization problem in Mathematica. The goal is to allocate a team of 11 workers, each with varying levels of proficiency in 6 skills, to 93 tasks over a 4-week period.
Problem Constraints:
Task Requirements: Tasks vary in complexity, requiring from 1 to 3 of the 6 available skills and ranging from 1 to 8 person-hours in duration.
Worker Assignments: Workers can be assigned individually or in pairs to tasks, provided they possess the necessary skills.
Time Constraints: The overall schedule must be optimized within the 4-week timeframe. A 1 shift per day vs. 2 shifts per day in the 4 week period is an option to reduce calendar time.
Optimization Goals:
Efficient Resource Allocation: Minimize idle worker hours and maximize task completion.
Skill Matching: Ensure that workers are assigned to tasks that align with their skill levels.
Workload Balancing: Distribute tasks equitably among workers to avoid bottlenecks and burnout.
Question:
What optimization techniques or algorithms might be suitable for addressing this problem? I'm particularly interested in approaches that can handle large solution spaces and complex constraints. Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.
I am not formally trained in mathematics, but I use Mathematica Home edition to model and create interesting problems for myself as learning opportunities, for math and Mathematica, based on real world challenges at my job, where I typically use Excel and brute force a solution based on a few manual iterations on a spreadsheet and pulling out any remaining hair on my head ;)
I recall an old schedule/shift optimization problem I had on my old notebook in Mathematica that figured out a week's schedule constrained by hour limits per day, 2 days off, and the potential to have part-time or full-time employees. The solution was very interesting in that it seemed to have an overstaffed day and more part-time employees than you would think.
Thank you.

Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory Tour now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

If you can please show what you have tried. This will certainly increase your chances of having someone help you. Otherwise it is unlikely that someone will code a full answer for you. You can also try to come up with a minimal example, which can be solved and then you can build up on this to deal with your full problem.

Thank you. I'm not looking for someone to code the full answer, more someone to even give me a category and point me to the attendant methods for solving such problems for me to do my own research, but thank you so much for your guidance.

I'm not familiar with this kind of optimization problem, but KnapsackSolve[ ] or FrobeniusSolve[ ] might be helpful. Please consult the Mathematica Document for more detail.

I am working on it currently, but I would suggest looking at FindMaximumFlow -> Applications -> Assignment Problem in the documentation. I believe you change either the VertexCapacity or EdgeCapacity to specify that workers can do multiple jobs, and multiple workers can be assigned to a specific job

Thank you, I will check this out. Exactly the direction I needed to start.

This sounds like a classic assignment problem which can be solved by linear programming. Check the Application examples in the LinearOptimization documentation.

Try googling “mathematica scheduling using combinatorics”

I found this Mathematica example in PDF I have been using and now I am trying to meld it with FindMaximumFlow to achieve my goals. Thanks @ydd!
https://www.se.edu/cmoretti/wp-content/uploads/sites/81/2015/08/Work-Scheduling-Example.pdf
